# secure copy through two hosts

Tags: linux, scp

I need to copy files that are behind a firewall server using scp.

normaly to login to the server I do the following

```
ssh -p 5023 firewall.domainname.fr
```

now i am in behind the firewall I connect to master

```
ssh master.domainname.fr
```

and here my files are in a folder path, for instance user/lolo/myfolder/

What is the right way to do a scp of all files in user/lolo/myfolder/* to my local computer

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually hopping through the firewall configure ssh to tunnel through it automatically.

In your `~/.ssh/config` put

```
Host master.domainname.fr
ProxyCommand ssh firewall.domainname.fr -p 5023 -W %h:%p
```

With the proxy command configured both `ssh master.domainname.fr` and `scp "master.domainname.fr:/user/lolo/myfolder/*" .` should just work from your local computer.

If you use an old ssh version (older than 5.4) that does not have the `-W` option, you will have to use something else, such as `nc`, for the proxy command.